# How can I restructure matrices to have non-zero elements close to the diagonal?

Tags: optimization, matrices

I have a matrix $C \in \mathbb{N}^{n \times n}$. Semantically, it is a confusion matrix where the element $c_{ij}$ denotes how often members of class $i$ are predicted by a given classifier as members of class $j$.

The order of elements does not matter, but $c_{ii}$ has to be the correct predction of class $i$. So for any given matrix $C$ you can swap columns if you swap the same rows.

How can I order the classes $1, \dots, n$ so that the biggest elements are close to the diagonal?

I thought one might pose this as an optimization problem, e.g. minimize
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n C_{ij} \cdot {|i-j|}$$

How could I minimize this?

### Code and example

I've already visualized a $369 \times 369$ matrix without any optimization. The confuscation matrix as JSON file and the [code are here](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/tree/master/ML/confusion-matrix).

Without modification, you get a score of `303535` for:

[image]

This looks as if there could be some improvement. A quick first thought was to just randomly swap rows. Letting this run for $10^4$ steps (~5 minutes) leads to a score of `82552` and a visualization which looks a bit cleaner:

[image]

Doing this, I realized that my score might also need some improvement. I instead of moving elements to the diagonal, it would be nice if big blocks within the matrix would only contain zeros.

The total number of possibilities to arrange the items in $C$ is equal to the number of permutations of a list of length $n$ and hence it is $n!$. Hence for $369$ classes it is already $369! \approx 10^{788}$ - too much to brute force.

### See also

- [My similar question on datascience.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/17079/8820)

Comment: It sounds like the problem is as follows: given a $n\times n$ matrix $C$, find a permutation $\pi$ on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ that minimizes the objective function $\Phi(\pi) = \sum_i \sum_j C_{\pi(i),\pi(j)} |i-j|$.  I don't know, but that smells like the sort of problem that might be NP-hard, so I don't hold out great hope for an efficient algorithm that finds the global optimum for this problem.  Perhaps you can find a different approach to your ultimate goal, that doesn't require solving this optimization problem.

Comment: @D.W. A global optimum is not necessary (although, of course, desirable). One way that could work well is a spring model: The $n$ elements all have 2 springs between them which say how strong they attract each other. But I have no idea how to solve this / if there are Python packages to model it.

Comment: Comment by a fellow student via Facebook: This problem reminds me of some results about graph compression: If we restrict ourselves to C_ij in {0,1} and interpret the matrix as an adjacency matrix of a graph, the problem becomes the minimum linear arrangement problem, which is already NP-hard (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.08820.pdf) ([original](https://www.facebook.com/martin.thoma/posts/1944954799070120?comment_id=1945252679040332&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R%22%7D))

Comment: Looks like the confusion matrix is sparse. If it is also symmetric, one can use the [Cuthill–McKee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill–McKee_algorithm) algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random swapping approach (simulated annealing with extremely low temperature) yields to a score of `64496` (20 minutes or so [with Python](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/tree/master/ML/confusion-matrix) and seed 0, ~60s with C++ and playing with seeds by a friend -.-). The permutation is

```
[213, 201, 367, 34, 368, 174, 249, 193, 159, 275, 225, 276, 194, 300, 191, 362, 113, 230, 158, 5, 4, 16, 352, 126, 265, 49, 224, 139, 187, 221, 228, 192, 156, 205, 204, 203, 241, 208, 214, 166, 67, 40, 52, 283, 124, 354, 133, 152, 173, 206, 235, 231, 237, 223, 217, 138, 118, 277, 361, 269, 344, 98, 258, 251, 30, 119, 122, 339, 309, 240, 245, 26, 226, 242, 232, 218, 110, 172, 86, 282, 297, 137, 21, 146, 62, 29, 293, 189, 171, 210, 84, 250, 136, 3, 304, 335, 154, 292, 78, 11, 266, 116, 164, 129, 148, 144, 195, 327, 306, 337, 9, 47, 168, 120, 128, 259, 261, 323, 254, 121, 200, 183, 256, 246, 85, 72, 305, 77, 76, 255, 336, 55, 46, 89, 73, 341, 100, 294, 145, 163, 87, 37, 185, 199, 15, 313, 88, 268, 264, 273, 69, 59, 44, 2, 106, 303, 82, 149, 326, 197, 279, 111, 38, 366, 57, 329, 68, 340, 257, 334, 93, 295, 286, 353, 365, 298, 285, 364, 91, 92, 90, 316, 252, 19, 165, 342, 125, 274, 176, 143, 239, 288, 95, 96, 324, 325, 28, 212, 253, 81, 79, 80, 318, 94, 299, 71, 291, 64, 132, 23, 278, 338, 308, 160, 7, 115, 247, 347, 147, 271, 188, 281, 272, 280, 155, 35, 349, 157, 177, 180, 202, 108, 350, 345, 97, 51, 141, 284, 355, 179, 42, 33, 70, 99, 45, 109, 178, 181, 103, 207, 220, 102, 211, 209, 196, 127, 41, 346, 351, 359, 320, 311, 13, 43, 287, 328, 357, 83, 310, 12, 161, 135, 131, 360, 39, 302, 1, 322, 123, 167, 6, 117, 31, 330, 356, 74, 75, 151, 104, 262, 289, 296, 140, 101, 236, 312, 343, 150, 348, 56, 234, 27, 14, 114, 331, 260, 314, 17, 54, 321, 105, 263, 130, 20, 186, 190, 63, 22, 162, 134, 363, 333, 301, 0, 169, 170, 175, 10, 112, 317, 61, 50, 248, 18, 315, 60, 32, 222, 244, 290, 48, 36, 307, 184, 58, 233, 238, 229, 227, 219, 153, 66, 319, 332, 358, 25, 53, 270, 182, 8, 216, 65, 24, 267, 107, 215, 142, 198, 243]
```

which corresponds to the symbol classes

```
['\blacktriangleright', '\nvDash', '\AE', '7', '\guillemotleft', '\perp',
'\bot', '\therefore', '\boxtimes', '\vdots', '\Leftarrow',
'\ddots', '\because', '\iddots',
'\multimap', '\L', '+', '\nearrow', '\boxplus', 'F', 'E', 'Q', '\checked', '\checkmark', '\rceil', 'h', '\uparrow',
'\div', '\doteq', '\longmapsto', '\mapsto', '\pitchfork', '\boxdot',
'\varsubsetneq', '\subsetneq', '\nsubseteq', '\nRightarrow', '\gtrless', '\triangleq', '\parr', '\Sigma', '\sum', 'k', '\sharp', '\#', '\sun', '\ast', '\star', '\not\equiv', '\neq', '\rightleftarrows',
'\rightleftharpoons', '\rightrightarrows', '\Longrightarrow', '\Rightarrow', '\pm',
'\dots', '\dotsc', '\aa', ']', '\ohm', '\Omega',
'\exists', '\ni', '3', '\}', '\pounds', '\mathscr{L}', '\mathcal{L}',
'\twoheadrightarrow', '\shortrightarrow', '\rightarrow', '\longrightarrow',
'\nrightarrow', '\rightharpoonup', '\hookrightarrow', '\cong', '\equiv',
'\Xi', '\diamondsuit', '\lozenge', '\diamond', 'V', '\vee', 'v', '2', '\sphericalangle', '\simeq', '\approx', '\gtrsim', '\nu', '\forall', '\triangleright',
'D', '\mathcal{D}', '\mathscr{D}',
'\barwedge', '\sqrt{}', '\iota', 'L', '\lfloor', '\{', '\coprod', '\amalg', '\sqcup', '\mp', '\between', '\mathds{E}', '\mathcal{F}', '\mathscr{F}', 'J', 'f', '\fint', '\S', '\mathsection', '\Im', '\nexists', '\mathfrak{X}', '\hbar', '\dag', '\nmid', '\vdash', '\notin', '\lightning', '\xi', '\zeta', '\mathcal{E}', '\varepsilon', '\epsilon', '\in', '\mathscr{E}', 'n', 'e', '\varrho', '\eta', '\mathscr{S}', '\int', '\square', '\sqcap', '\prod', '\Pi', '\pi', '\models', '\vDash', 'P', '\mathcal{P}', '\rho', '[', '\lceil', '\llbracket', '\Gamma', 'r', 'c', 'C', '\subset',
'\mathcal{C}', '\Lambda', '\wedge', '\mathds{C}', '\varpropto', '\infty', '\propto', '\alpha', '\ae', 'p', '\mathds{P}', '\gamma', '\mathscr{P}',
'\wp', '\mathscr{C}', '\varphi', '\triangledown', '\nabla', '\diameter',
'\o', '\varnothing', '\emptyset', '\O', '\phi', '\Phi', '\tau',
'\mathcal{T}', '\top', 'T', '\oint', '\celsius', '\%', '\rrbracket', '\frown', '\cap', '\curvearrowright', '\clubsuit', '\psi', '\Psi', '\mathbb{1}', '\mathds{1}', '1', '\trianglelefteq', '\ell', '\lambda',
'\kappa', '\varkappa', '\mathcal{X}', '\chi', '\vartriangle', '\Delta',
'\triangle', 'x', '\times', 'X', '\aleph', '\mathscr{H}', '\mathcal{H}',
'\rtimes', 'H', '\$', '\vartheta', '\astrosun', '\odot',
'\|', '\parallel', '\angle', '/', '\prime', '\circledcirc', '8', '\leftmoon',
'\ltimes', '\prec', '\preceq', '\sqsubseteq', '\subseteq', '\female',
'\venus', '\omega', 'j', '\setminus', '\backslash', '\Bowtie', '\bowtie',
'a', '6', '\delta', '\partial', 'd', '\supseteq', '\succ', '\succeq',
'\geq', '\geqslant', '\searrow', '\leq', '\leqslant', '\lesssim',
'\preccurlyeq', '\circledR', '\sigma', '\mars', '\male', '\mathbb{H}',
'\mathfrak{A}',
'\mathcal{N}', 'N', 'b', '\flat', '\mathds{N}', '\mathbb{N}', '\mu', '\mathcal{M}', 'M',
'\circledast', '\otimes',
'\oplus', '\ss', '\beta', '\mathcal{B}', 'B', '\mathfrak{S}', '\&',
'\with', 'G', '\copyright', '4', '\mathds{Q}', '\mathbb{Q}', '\theta',
'\Theta', '\ominus', '<', '\langle', '\heartsuit', '\blacksquare',
'\bullet', '\cdot', '\circlearrowright', '\mathcal{O}', '\degree',
'\circ', '\fullmoon', 'o', '\circlearrowleft', '0', 'O',
'\mathbb{R}', '\mathds{R}', '\Re', '\mathcal{R}', 'R',
'm', '\mathfrak{M}', '>', '\rangle', '\cup', 'U', '\sim', '\backsim', 'w', 'W', '\lhd', '\triangleleft', '\AA', '\mathscr{A}', '\mathcal{A}', 'A', '\varoiint', '\oiint', '\asymp', 'K', '-', '\mathcal{U}', 'u', 'i', '\varpi', 'S',
'\mathcal{S}', 's', '5', '\leftarrow', '\mapsfrom', '\neg', 'g', '9',
'\mathcal{G}', '\dashv', 'q',
'\leadsto', '\rightsquigarrow', '\leftrightarrow', '\Leftrightarrow', '\Longleftrightarrow',
'\wr', 'z', '\mathcal{Z}', '\mathds{Z}', '\mathbb{Z}', 'Z',
'l', '|', '\mid', 'I', '\downarrow',
'y', 'Y', '\rfloor', '\supset', '\Downarrow', '\uplus', '\Vdash', '\upharpoonright']
```

As expected, this method automatically finds groups of classes which are similar, such as `'D', '\mathcal{D}', '\mathscr{D}'`.

It leads to the following confusion matrix:

[image]

### Thoughs about good solutions / minima

This optimization problem will most likely get the best results if all groups of similar classes are together. For [this dataset](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.08380), the groups are  D-shaped, O-shaped, arrow-shaped, ...

For a good classifier, it is expected that there are many errors between members of a group and few (even none) between groups. Hence the ordering of groups does not matter (much).

If the classifier can distinguish many classes really well, a lot of groups exist. If there are $k$ groups, there will be $k!$ solutions to the confusion matrix optimization problem which will have almost the same score. For the HASYv2 dataset and the CNN classifier I expect there to be at least 50 groups (hence $50! \approx 10^{64}$ similar solutions which are all close to the minima / minimum.